# Multiple simultaneous Xdebug connections on Vagrant VM in Intellij

Tags: php, intellij-idea, vagrant, xdebug

I'm running Apache in a Vagrant VM. I run my PHP Remote Debug configuration in Intellij to listen for Xdebug connections. I'd like to debug two requests simultaneously. I do one request to `first.php` and another request to `second.php` using the browser on my host (Google Chrome).

[image: Code with breakpoints]

The debugger pauses execution for the request to `first.php`, but the request to `second.php` is not executed (breakpoint is not reached) before the first request is done. I use the following configuration:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_connect_back=true
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.idekey=MY_AWESOME_KEY
```

[image: Intellij Xdebug config]
[image: PHP Remote Debug configuration]

I expect to be able to pause the debugger in both files simultaneous. Why is the second request blocked till the first is done? How can I debug these two requests simultaneously?

Comment: I've done this many times, and without problems. So there is perhaps something else that makes this break - perhaps a locked session?

Comment: How can I check if the session is locked?

Answer (score 2):

Don't run the PHP Remote Debug configuration! Just use the menu "Run -> Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections" and it works.